# ASP.NET Webforms Deployment & Markup Changes

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

In ASP.NET Web Forms, I know when the C# changes the primary DLL also needs to be deployed.  I also know when the markup (.aspx, .master) changes where new controls are added, the primary DLL needs to be deployed.

What about when the markup (.aspx, .master) changes and no controls are added?  Can the .aspx or .master page be changed without deploying the associated DLL?  I see 2 scenarios that may have different answers:

1. Simple markup changes (e.g. HTML, CSS. JS)
2. Dynamic changes in the markup (e.g. add <%=Page.ResolveUrl("~/test.aspx") %>)

### **Note:

Ideally I'd deploy the whole app on any change, but I'm dealing with a fragile legacy app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.aspx` or `.master` pages be changed without deploying the associated DLL **provided** changed contents/controls don't change the interaction with the server-side code. For example in `Home.aspx` you add a paragraph `<p>Sometext</p>` deploy just `Home.aspx`, application would keep working. 
On the other hand, obviously, if any control name is changed/event is added, you need to deploy associated DLL (after necessary updates).

I hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks @Sami!  What about if some dynamic C# is added to the .aspx or .master?  For example `<%=Page.ResolveUrl("~test.aspx") %>`

Comment: It's fine, you don't need to redeploy DLLs provided no changes made in test.aspx page.
Wondering if you accept as answer if it helps! Thanks